# Mobile <div> hamburger menu items blocking other links on page

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to figure out why on mobile devices (my website: https://www.mchna.org/?p=news) (can be reproduced in desktop browser emulating mobile as well) the div hamburger menu items (though not visible unless the hamburger menu is expanded) are laying on top of the page even though the hamburger menu has not been expanded. I've been playing around with all the  tags, but to no avail. This causes the links at the bottom of my page to not work correctly. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try wrapping the div #main-wrap on the news page inside a div #main-content similar to the markup on the other pages where this is working.

Edit: The reason for this happening is the `z-index: 8` on the #navmobile which moves this "layer" in front of the other content. By giving the content `position: relative` and `z-index: 10` (or anything higher than 8) it should work.

Comment: You're a life saver! It's been a long week! Thank you so much!